# android: intent passing null

Tags: android, string, android-intent, null

I have to pass a string from an activity to another.

in Activiy1 i made:

```
String modello=nomiImmagini[position];
Intent nomeModello = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
nomeModello.putExtra("modello", modello);
```

where the value of array nomiImmagini[position] is not null, if i made a toast like

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Selezionato " + nomiImmagini[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

it work correctly.

in activity2 I made:

```
String modello = getIntent().getStringExtra("modello");
```

but here the result is null!

How can I fix this? I'm a beginner in Android and maybe I not understand the intent.

Comment: are you using `nomeModello` to start   `Activity2`?

Comment: Also, where at in `Activity2` do you have `String modello = getIntent().getStringExtra("modello");`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the intent when you are launching Activity2:

```
Activity1.this.startActivity(nomeModello);
```

Then in the onCreate of your Acitivty2:

```
String modello = getIntent().getExtras().getString("modello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have LaunchMode for activity2 : singleInstance in manifest:

```
<activity
        ...
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        ...
>
```

that would cause to call current instance if it exists instead of creating new one.
so I would suggest to add this flag to your intent :

```
nomeModello.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

so your code would be :

```
String modello=nomiImmagini[position];
Intent nomeModello = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
nomeModello.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
nomeModello.putExtra("modello", modello);
```

and as BlackBelt mentioned, you should call activity2 by this intent  ***nomeModell*** so it will be something like:
startActivity(nomeModello);

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to an already confused user to add things that may not be needed and could cause unwanted results.

Answer (score 0):

In first activity u need this:

`startActivity(nomeModello);`

and in second where u get data, if that doesnt work, try this:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null)
        String modello = extras.getString("modello");
```